# Does the following proof use the axiom of choice.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was looking at a proof for the countability of set of isolated points of any subset of separable metric space posted on another stack exchange [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1789217/819771). I suspect (but I'm not sure) that this proof uses the axiom of choice in determining $r_x$ and the function $f(x)$ discussed in the answer.

Can someone help confirm if this is truly the case. If yes is there a way to proof this without using the axiom of choice?

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. I think that asking for clarification of an answer on the site, with the difficulty explained is fine. It's not linking off-site.

Comment: It definitely uses the axiom of choice twice: once to fix a a radii for balls centered at any point $x \in C$ (the $r_{x}$'s) and then for the definition of $f$ there's a second use of the axiom of choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no actual use of choice. We can always assume the distance is rational, since once $B_r(x)=\{x\}$, then for every $r'<r$, it is also true that $B_{r'}(x)=\{x\}$, so in particular we can assume that $r$ was a rational number. Since the rationals are countable, we can enumerate them and choose the least one (in the enumeration!) that works.

And since $A$, the dense set, is countable, we can again enumerate it and choose the least one.

So, while the phrasing is one that relies on choice, in actuality, we can easily avoid it.

Comment: I'm confused about your use of "least". I thought the set of positive rationals isn't well ordered and doesn't have a least element.

Comment: Never mind, I get what you meant. You just defined $r_x$ and $f(x)$ using their enumerations.

Comment: @samuelokon Under the normal order, this is true. But since $\mathbb{Q}$ can be put into bijection with the well-ordered set $\mathbb{N}$, we can use this bijection to give $\mathbb{Q}$ a well-order. We use this well-order to make all choices.

Comment: @MarkSaving sorry if I'm dragging this issue longer than usual. I'm trying to understand all the edge cases. In using the bijection to make choices, won't we have to make a choice on the bijection we use. Since there may be multiple bijections.

Comment: @samuelokon We are only making at most one choice. Making finitely many choices doesn’t require the axiom of choice. And the standard proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ can be put into bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ can easily be seen to define a specific bijection between the two of them, so we don’t even need to make one arbitrary choice.